# Cant decompress message from NetworkSteam(zlib)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, networkstream

I have problem.
I send XML request to NetworkStream, and i get answer [head] - not compressed, and [body] - compressed zlib.

When i used code

```
public static string UnZipStr(byte[] input)
    {
        using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(input))
        {
            using (DeflateStream gzip =
              new DeflateStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader =
                  new StreamReader(gzip, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get error

> System.IO.InvalidDataException: "Bad data detected during decoding."

I did delele [head](just dont read first 100 byte = size head), but result is same.

When i used it

```
 private MemoryStream Deflate(byte[] data, int level, bool zlib)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        var deflater = new Deflater(level, !zlib);
        using (DeflaterOutputStream outStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(memoryStream, deflater))
        {
            outStream.IsStreamOwner = false;
            outStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            outStream.Flush();
            outStream.Finish();
        }
        return memoryStream;
    }
```

My message is not true read. I dont know level, because i used all - from 1 to 9. And two time - with flags true and false.

> Piece of uncompress message: 
>   (��]�r�F\u0012}�W�����n��r�5\0F���ƅ\n��uT[�J�-���_��(Q$H��,��v�+���i@����\u0003��Vl˔h���ӧ/x������ã��\u000e��z��-g���O��\u001f��ۭ<�~\U00017b7f=���������_8Γ�\aG��;t���\u000f/
>   )

**How can i decompress my message?**

p.s. when server send me non-compress message - i get true message.

all my code. I just dont know, where can i mistake?

```
 public string postXMLData(string request)
    {
        int port = XXXXX;
        string ip = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XX";
        int idClient = XXX;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        int byteSizeBuf = 1024;
        byte[] buff = new byte[byteSizeBuf * 100];

        byte[] byteRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);
        ConnectionMode connectionMode = ConnectionMode.Plain;
        QueryHeader test = new QueryHeader(idClient, byteRequest.Length, connectionMode);

        byte[] data = new byte[byteSizeBuf];
        byte[] res = new byte[test.MessageLength + byteRequest.Length];

        test.HeaderData.CopyTo(res, 0);
        byteRequest.CopyTo(res, test.HeaderData.Length);

        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        tcpClient.Connect(ip, port);
        NetworkStream netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        netStream.Write(res, 0, res.Length);

        string final = response.ToString(); //куда записывать

        int pos = 0;
        do
        {
            int bytes = netStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            response.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
            data.CopyTo(buff, pos);
            pos += data.Length;
        }
        while (netStream.DataAvailable);

        string decodedStr = UnZipStr(buff);

        netStream.Close();
        tcpClient.Close();

        return final;
    }
```

Comment: Please create and post a [mcve], which means you will post how you compress and then decompress some data that is part of the example. Likely this will either help you yourself spot the mistake, or it will give us something to test and debug to try to help you. There's too many unknowns here so other than saying "You did something wrong" there's not likely much anyone can do here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem with your posted code. The problem must be in the code you didn't post. So, whatever is done in between of `Deflate(...)` and `UnZipStr(...)` it must have changed your compressed data.

Just try it yourself by directly using the output of `Deflate(...)` as the input of `UnZipStr(...)` :

```
Console.WriteLine(UnZipStr(
    Deflate(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!"), 9, false).ToArray()
));
```